# How to make a function that compares strings?

Tags: string, function, swift, compare

I want to make a function which compares strings.
I don't want to use equal operators (==), I want it worked only with Swift language.

First I made a function which takes 2 strings, and returns bool type.
then I looped these strings with for in syntax.
And want to compare these characters, if strings have equal value, it should return true, if not, then false. Is there any better way?

```
func isEqual(str1:String, str2:String) -> Bool {
    var result = false

    for char in str1 {

    }
    for char2 in str2 {

    }
    //Compare characters.
    return result
}
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use `==`?

Comment: What do you mean with *"I want it worked only with Swift language"* ?

Comment: @ABakerSmith because I'm practicing...

Comment: @Martin R I mean I don't want use such as 'NSComparisonResult'.I want to use only swift basic syntaxes..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`==` works fine with Strings in Swift. For *educational purposes*
(as I conclude from your comment *"because I'm practicing..."*)
you can implement it as:

```
func myStringCompare(str1 : String, str2 : String) -> Bool {

    if count(str1) != count(str2) {
        return false
    }
    for (c1, c2) in zip(str1, str2) {
        if c1 != c2 {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

`zip(str1, str2)` returns a sequence of pairs from the given
sequences, this is a convenient way to enumerate the strings
"in parallel".

Once you have understood how it works, you can shorten it,
for example to:

```
func myStringCompare(str1 : String, str2 : String) -> Bool {

    return count(str1) == count(str2) && !contains(zip(str1, str2), { $0 != $1 })
}
```

Comparing the string length is necessary because the `zip()` sequence
terminates as soon as one of the strings is exhausted. Have a look at
@drewag's answer to [In Swift I would like to "join" two sequences in to a sequence of tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25153477/in-swift-i-would-like-to-join-two-sequences-in-to-a-sequence-of-tuples)
for an alternative `Zip2WithNilPadding` sequence.

If you don't want to use the built-in `zip()` function (again for
educational/self-learning purposes!) then you can use the fact
that Strings are *sequences*, and enumerate them in parallel using
the sequence *generator*. This would work  not only for strings but
for arbitrary sequences, as long as the underlying elements can
be tested for equality, so let's make it a *generic* function:

```
func mySequenceCompare<S : SequenceType where S.Generator.Element : Equatable>(lseq : S, rseq : S) -> Bool {

    var lgen = lseq.generate()
    var rgen = rseq.generate()

    // First elements (or `nil`):
    var lnext = lgen.next()
    var rnext = rgen.next()
    while let lelem = lnext, relem = rnext {
        if lelem != relem {
            return false
        }
        // Next elements (or `nil`):
        lnext = lgen.next()
        rnext = rgen.next()
    }

    // Are both sequences exhausted?
    return lnext == nil && rnext == nil
}
```

Tests:

```
mySequenceCompare("xa", "xb")  // false
mySequenceCompare("xa", "xa")  // true
mySequenceCompare("a", "aa")   // false
mySequenceCompare("aa", "a")   // false
```

Comment: thnkas Martin for a great lesson!! It really helped me to understand swift. I'm also trying to put those characters to a new array and compare each items in array. :) thank you.

Answer (score 2):

My solution differ a little as I didn't know about the zip operator, I guess is not as efficient as the one post by Martin great use of tuple.

Great question alphonse

```
func isEqual(str1:String, str2:String) -> Bool {
    if count(str1) != count(str2){
        return false
    }
    for var i = 0; i < count(str1); ++i {
        let idx1 = advance(str1.startIndex,i)
        let idx2 = advance(str2.startIndex,i)
        if str1[idx1] != str2[idx2]{
           return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

As pointed by Martin each string needs its own index, as explained by him:
 "The "trick" is that "" is an "extended grapheme cluster" and consists of two Unicode code points, but counts as one Swift character."

Link for more details about [extended grapheme cluster](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html)

Comment: You must not use the `idx` created from `str1` with a different string `str2`. Try `isEqual("foo", "foo")`  :)

Comment: Very trick, I try few different options but I didn't use the emoticons, thanks I will update it

Comment: Now it works :) – The "trick" is that the "Regional Indicator" "" is an "extended grapheme cluster" and consists of *two* Unicode code points, but counts as *one* Swift character (in contrast to Foundation NSString, where it counts as *four* UTF-16 `unichar`)

Comment: Thanks @MartinR just learn something new that may avoid a very difficult bug to find in the future

Comment: @alphonse it helped me too, to be honest wasn't trivial come up with this code and in the end I learned this new think about strings I didn't know