# Extracting a specific part of a 2d list Python

Tags: python, algorithm

Say I have a 2d list like below for example:

```
x = [[31, 34], [32, 34], [33, 34], [31, 35], [33, 35], [31,36], [32, 36]]
```

And,

```
y = [[31, 34], [33, 34], [31, 36]]
```

They are list of pixel coordinates. Basically what I am trying to do is extract only the elements (coordinates) in the list **x** which are **NOT** present in list **y**.

Please suggest an efficient way to do this. As I will be using this for lots of data I am worried about the speed. Thanks.

***Edit: There is no particular pattern in the element indexes. So, it might be a search based method but I am not sure.***

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30653705/572670

Comment: `new = [i for i in x if i not in y]`

Comment: @MalikBrahimi While simple and clean, this is a very inefficient way to achieve it, and may be an issue if the list grows.