# Which is the best and the most efficient way to find and store non existent values between two arrays in both sides?

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm

Perhaps this has been asked several times but I can't find the right answer so here goes.

I have two arrays: one with `~135732` and the other one with `~135730` elements. I need to find which items are on the first but not on the second and viceverse and don't know is there is an easy way to achieve that.

This is what I would do it:

```
$countArr1 = count($arr1);
$countArr2 = count($arr2);

for($i=0; $i < $countArr1; $i++) {
    // Check whether current element on $arr1 is on $arr2 or not
    if (!in_array($arr1[$i], $arr2)) {
        // if it doesn't then add it to $newArr 
        $newArr[] = $arr1[$i];
    }    
}
```

Then I would do the same but inverse for `$arr2`. In *huge* arrays could take a while and also could kill memory or server resources, even if it's executed from CLI so which is the best and the most efficient, regarding use of resources, way to achieve this?

**EDIT**

Let's clear this a bit. I get `$arr1` from DB and `$arr2` comes from other place. So the big idea is to find which items needs to be updated and which ones needs to be added also which ones needs to be marked as obsolete. In less and common words:

- if element is on `$arr1` but doesn't exists on `$arr2` should be marked as **obsolete**
- if element comes in `$arr2` btu doesn't exists on `$arr1` then needs to be added (created)
- otherwise that element just need to be updated

Clear enough? Feel free to ask everything in order to help on this

**EDIT 2**

Based on @dakkaron answer I made this code:

```
// $arr1 and $arr2 are previously built

$sortArr1 = asort($arr1);
$sortArr2 = asort($arr2);

$countArr1 = count($sortArr1);
$countArr2 = count($sortArr2);

$i = $j = 0;

$updArr = $inactiveArr = $newArr = [];

echo "original arr1 count: ", count($arr1), "\n";
echo "original arr2 count: ", count($arr2), "\n";

echo "arr1 count: ", $countArr1, "\n";
echo "arr2 count: ", $countArr2, "\n";

while ( $i < $countArr1 && $j < $countArr2) {
    if ($sortArr1[$i] == $sortArr2[$j]) {
        //Handle equal values
        $updArr[] = $sortArr1[$i];
        $i++; $j++;
    } else if ($sortArr1[$i] < $sortArr2[$j]) {
        //Handle values that are in arr1 but not in arr2
        $inactiveArr[] = $sortArr1[$i];
        $i++;
    } else {
        //Handle values that are in arr2 but not in arr1
        $newArr[] = $sortArr2[$j];
        $j++;
    }
}

echo "items update: ", count($updArr), "\n", "items inactive: ", count($inactiveArr), "\n", "items new: ", count($newArr), "\n";
```

And I got this output:

```
original arr1 count: 135732
original arr2 count: 135730
arr1 count: 1
arr2 count: 1
items update: 1
items inactive: 0
items new: 0
```

Why sort count returns 1?

Comment: You can write it in 2 temp files. Sort by php or system utility, then compare it, reading line by line. If memory  allows, do this in memory. Because compare 2 sorted arrays is not problem :)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php

Comment: What kind of values are stored in the array?

Comment: Closely related that I am tempted to call a dupe (still minor differences though): [Find delta of two lists](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30653705/572670)

Comment: @amit what about if I don't have the unique id?

Comment: @ReynierPM Then do the same while using a multiset/multimap rather than a set/map, basically.

Comment: @amit sorry but I am not following you, can you post an answer with pseudo-code?

Comment: So, judging from the other thread, most efficient is either O(nlogm) time and O(1) space (sorting and checking each element) or O(n+m) time and O(m) space, where `m` is the shorter list and `n` is the longer one. (All other solutions are O(nlogn) and O(n) time+space)

Comment: @ReynierPM asort return boolean. It sort array given as param

Comment: `asort` returns boolean... http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.asort.php

Comment: in your code replace "$sortArr1 = asort($arr1);" with "asort($arr1);" and all occurrences of "$sortArr1" with "$arr1" (and do the same for $arr2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution I can think of would be to first `sort` both arrays and then compare them from the bottom up.

- Start with the lowest element in both arrays and compare them.
- If they are equal, take them and move up one element on both arrays.
- If they are different, move up one element on the array with the lower value.
- If you reached the end of one of the arrays you are done.

After the sorting this should take about O(n) complexity.

This is a bit of code in pseudocode:

```
arr1 = ...
arr2 = ...

arr1.sort();
arr2.sort();

i1 = 0;
i2 = 0;
while (i1<arr1.length() && i2<arr2.length()) {
    if (arr1[i1]==arr2[i2]) {
        //Handle equal values
        i1++; i2++;
    } else if (arr1[i1]<arr2[i2]) {
        //Handle values that are in arr1 but not in arr2
        i1++;
    } else {
        //Handle values that are in arr2 but not in arr1
        i2++;
    }
}
```

Other than that, if you don't want to implement it yourself, just use [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)

Comment: Can you write a small piece of code just to show me the algorithm? Thx

Answer (score 3):

You could take avantage of `array_diff`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

### Edit

A php function construct is more likely to perform better than an equivalent user-defined one. Searching I found [this](http://shiplu.mokadd.im/36/fastes-way-to-find-difference-of-very-large-php-arrays/), but the size of your array is way smaller, and in the end I believe you should benchmark a prototype script with candidate solutions.

See my last comment.

Comment: And http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php depending on what they want.

Comment: I wonder how efficient that array_diff is? (in terms of speed)

Comment: `array_diff` may be the simplest but probably not the most efficient solution: it makes a copy of both arrays, sorts them, and enumerates the values in parallel. So we have a doubling of memory and a runtime of probably O(n*log n).

Comment: https://gist.github.com/oanhnn/1a893702652ed8b91ba7 the OP can add their current algorithm and settle this.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution i can think of is to `sort` the second array, and try to look for values from the first array using `binary search`,
this would take O(nLog(n)) complexity

Comment: What happens if second array has more elements than first one? Should I compare them first and iterate over the greater?

Comment: hmm, this has nothing to do with arrays size :). you are just looking for the first array values in the second one.

Comment: Can you put a simple code just to show me? I am not familiar with `binary search`

Answer (score 1):

Fill hashtable-based dictionary/map (don't know how it is called in PHP) with the second array elements, and check whether every element of the first array presents in this dictionary.
Usual complexity O(N)

```
for A in arr2
   map.insert(A)
for B in arr1
   if not map.contains(B) then
         element B  is on $arr1 but doesn't exists on $arr2
```

note that this approach doesn't address all problems in your edited question

Comment: Can you write a small piece of pseudocode? I will do my part on PHP side but need to see what are you talking about first

Answer (score 1):

Since your values are strings, you could take the advantage of PHP’s implementation of arrays using a hash-table internally with O(1) for key lookups:

```
$diff = [];

// A \ B
$lookup = array_flip($b); // O(n)
foreach ($a as $value) { // O(n)
    if (!isset($lookup[$value])) $diff[] = $value;
}

// B \ A
$lookup = array_flip($a); // O(n)
foreach ($b as $value) { // O(n)
    if (!isset($lookup[$value])) $diff[] = $value;
}
```

So in total, it’s O(n) in both space and time.

Of course, in the end you should benchmark it to see if it’s actually more efficient than other solutions here.

Comment: And how this will help me to get Inserted, Deleted and Updated items? Sorry I am not following you